# multiple form using twig

Tags: php, symfony

I was wondering, is there a way to display several forms using a single controller ?

I got a list of items. I get them all by using Doctrine findAll, and return them using the controller.

I display them by using twig :

```
{% for item in items %}
<form method="post" {{ form_enctype(dislike) }}>
    {{ form_widget(dislike) }}
</form>
{% endfor %}
```

For every item displayed, I got a div with a simple form button.

Unfortunately this doesn't work at all ! it only displays a button in the very first div, even though I got several items to display.

Any idea why ?

Comment: dislike is wrong. Maybe you mean item.dislike?

Comment: what are items? Are they entities?

Comment: I tried zith item.dislike, item had no "dislike" attributes.

@reafle , yes, they are entities